# Rails: How to get a collection of users based on a method returning true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example:

```
def some_boolean_method?
  # returns true or false
end
```

I want to do something like this: `User.where(some_boolean_method: true)`. That's how I'd do it with an actual column, but how can I do it with a method instead?

Comment: Have you considered using a scope?

Comment: Depending on  what `some_boolean_method?` does you might want to find a way to handle in in the DB instead. Sifting though records in Ruby is often slower and eats memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use it with select, since the methods are abstractions of the model, the methods are not available in the database.

```
User.where(...).select { |u| u if u.some_boolean_method }.reject(&:blank?)
```

Or:

```
User.select { |u| u if u.some_boolean_method }.reject(&:blank?)
```

Assuming that the method **some_boolean_method** is in the user implementation or at least it uses user for making the decision.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
User.all.select(&:some_boolean_method)
```

Be careful, this will load **all** users from the DB to the memory, and keep only the ones where `some_boolean_method` returns `true`. This can cause problems if you have too many users (in this case consider using `find_each`).